# Replace other columns of duplicate rows with first unique value and create lookup

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the data -

```
Account_Number  Dummy_Account
1050080713252   ACC0000000000001
1050223213427   ACC0000000000002
1050080713252   ACC0000000169532
1105113502309   ACC0000000123005
1100043521537   ACC0000000000004
1100045301840   ACC0000000000005
1105113502309   ACC0000000000040
```

Rows `1,3` have duplicate values in `Account_Number`. So do rows `4,7`. 
I need to replace the duplicate values in `Account_Number` with the same values in `Dummy_Account`. So for `1050080713252`, both rows `1,3` should have same dummy values `ACC0000000000001`. But instead of replacing directly, I want to keep the original mapping.

My expected output is -

```
Account_Number_Map      Dummy_Account_Original
ACC0000000000001    ACC0000000000001
ACC0000000000002    ACC0000000000002
ACC0000000000001    ACC0000000169532
ACC0000000123005    ACC0000000123005
ACC0000000000004    ACC0000000000004
ACC0000000000005    ACC0000000000005
ACC0000000123005    ACC0000000000040
```

Since `ACC0000000169532` is the duplicate `Dummy_Account` w.r.t `Account_Number`, I want to create a lookup that replaces this with `ACC0000000000001`

**What I have tried**

I started with creating a `dict` like this -

```
maps = dict(zip(df.Dummy_Account, df.Account_Number))
```

I figured creating a `dict` that will have the original `Dummy_Account` values as `key` and new `Dummy_Account` values as `value`
But I am a little lost. My dataset is large so I am also looking at optimized solutions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `drop_duplicates`, create a Series which you'll pass to `map`:

```
m = df.drop_duplicates('Account_Number', keep='first')\
      .set_index('Account_Number')\
      .Dummy_Account

df.Account_Number = df.Account_Number.map(m)
```

```
df

     Account_Number     Dummy_Account
0  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000000001
1  ACC0000000000002  ACC0000000000002
2  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000169532
3  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000123005
4  ACC0000000000004  ACC0000000000004
5  ACC0000000000005  ACC0000000000005
6  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000000040
```

---

**Timings**

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 1000000, ignore_index=True)
```

```
# jezrael's solution

%%timeit
v = df.sort_values('Account_Number')
v['Account_Number'] = v['Dummy_Account'].mask(v.duplicated('Account_Number')).ffill()
v.sort_index()

315 ms ± 1.65 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

```
# in this post

%%timeit
m = df.drop_duplicates('Account_Number', keep='first')\
      .set_index('Account_Number')\
      .Dummy_Account

df.Account_Number.map(m)

163 ms ± 3.56 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Note that the performance will depend on your actual data.

Comment: hmph! Both yours and @jezrael's solutions work... so upvote to both.. any optimization stats on what works better?

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Good question. I think both solutions are good. Map may be faster. You can try timing both solutions on your data with %timeit and accept the fastest!

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Added timings. But beware that the performance depends on your data.

Comment: @COLDSPEED - You think SO should allow you to upvote twice, but can't! I will settle for accepting :-)

Comment: @VivekKalyanarangan Happy enough it helped. Good day!

Answer (score 4):

**Option 1**
I'd use `groupby` and `transform` with `first`.
`transform` will broadcast the first encountered value across all instances
of the group.

```
df.assign(
    Account_Number=
    df.groupby('Account_Number')
      .Dummy_Account
      .transform('first')
)

     Account_Number     Dummy_Account
0  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000000001
1  ACC0000000000002  ACC0000000000002
2  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000169532
3  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000123005
4  ACC0000000000004  ACC0000000000004
5  ACC0000000000005  ACC0000000000005
6  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000000040
```

---

**Option 2**
Use Numpy's `np.unique` to get at an index of first values and an inverse.
The index (`idx`) identifies where the first unique positions of `'Account_Number'` occured.  I use this to slice `'Dummy_Account'`.  I then use the inverse array (`inv`) intended to put the unique values back into place but instead I use it on the things that were in those same positions from the coincident array.

```
u, idx, inv = np.unique(
    df.Account_Number.values,
    return_index=True,
    return_inverse=True
)

df.assign(
    Account_Number=
    df.Dummy_Account.values[idx][inv]
)

     Account_Number     Dummy_Account
0  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000000001
1  ACC0000000000002  ACC0000000000002
2  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000169532
3  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000123005
4  ACC0000000000004  ACC0000000000004
5  ACC0000000000005  ACC0000000000005
6  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000000040
```

---

**Option 3**
Or using `pd.factorize` and `pd.Series.duplicated`.
Similar to option 2, however I let `duplicated` play the role of identifying where the first values are.  I then slice the coincident values with the resulting boolean array then invert it with the result of `pd.factorize`.  `f` plays the same exact role as `inv` from option 2.

```
d = ~df.Account_Number.duplicated().values
f, u = pd.factorize(df.Account_Number.values)

df.assign(
    Account_Number=
    df.Dummy_Account.values[d][f]
)

     Account_Number     Dummy_Account
0  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000000001
1  ACC0000000000002  ACC0000000000002
2  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000169532
3  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000123005
4  ACC0000000000004  ACC0000000000004
5  ACC0000000000005  ACC0000000000005
6  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000000040
```

---

**Time Tests**

**Results**

```
res.plot(loglog=True)
```

[image]

```
res.div(res.min(1), 0)

              jez      cold      pir1      pir2      pir3
10       4.524811  3.819322  2.870916  1.000000  1.238144
30       4.833144  4.093932  3.310285  1.000000  1.382189
100      4.863337  4.048008  3.146154  1.000000  1.320060
300      5.144460  3.894850  3.157636  1.000000  1.357779
1000     4.870499  3.742524  2.348021  1.000000  1.069559
3000     5.375105  3.432398  1.852771  1.126024  1.000000
10000    7.100372  4.335100  1.890134  1.551161  1.000000
30000    7.227139  3.993985  1.530002  1.594531  1.000000
100000   8.052324  3.811728  1.380440  1.708170  1.000000
300000   8.690613  4.204664  1.539624  1.942090  1.000000
1000000  7.787494  3.668117  1.498758  2.129085  1.000000
```

**Setup**

```
def jez(d):
    v = d.sort_values('Account_Number')
    v['Account_Number'] = v['Dummy_Account'].mask(v.duplicated('Account_Number')).ffill()
    return v.sort_index()

def cold(d):
    m = d.drop_duplicates('Account_Number', keep='first')\
         .set_index('Account_Number')\
         .Dummy_Account

    return d.assign(Account_Number=d.Account_Number.map(m))

def pir1(d):
    return d.assign(
        Account_Number=
        d.groupby('Account_Number')
         .Dummy_Account
         .transform('first')
    )

def pir2(d):
    u, idx, inv = np.unique(
        d.Account_Number.values,
        return_index=True,
        return_inverse=True
    )

    return d.assign(
        Account_Number=
        d.Dummy_Account.values[idx][inv]
    )

def pir3(d):
    p = ~d.Account_Number.duplicated().values
    f, u = pd.factorize(d.Account_Number.values)

    return d.assign(
        Account_Number=
        d.Dummy_Account.values[p][f]
    )


res = pd.DataFrame(
    index=[10, 30, 100, 300, 1000, 3000, 10000,
           30000, 100000, 300000, 1000000],
    columns='jez cold pir1 pir2 pir3'.split(),
    dtype=float
)

np.random.seed([3, 1415])
for i in res.index:
    d = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        Account_Number=np.random.randint(i // 2, size=i),
        Dummy_Account=range(i)
    ))
    d = pd.concat([df] * i, ignore_index=True)
    for j in res.columns:
        stmt = f'{j}(d)'
        setp = f'from __main__ import {j}, d'
        res.at[i, j] = timeit(stmt, setp, number=100)
```

Comment: AFK atm, will add timings as soon as I can :)

Comment: oh the syntax looks counter-intuitive to me but does the job perfectly! Thanks @piRSquared

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ nvm, I went ahead and put it together.

Comment: @piRSquared - I think better is some more groups dataframe, because in your sample are only huge groups dataframes.

Comment: @jezrael yeah, that would be good.  I'll try to create a better simulation of a growing dataframe.

Comment: @jezrael fixed.  The number of groups stays ~half of total rows.

Answer (score 3):

Use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) and replace duplicated values by `ffill`:

```
df = df.sort_values('Account_Number')
df['Account_Number'] = df['Dummy_Account'].mask(df.duplicated('Account_Number')).ffill()
df = df.sort_index()
print (df)
     Account_Number     Dummy_Account
0  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000000001
1  ACC0000000000002  ACC0000000000002
2  ACC0000000000001  ACC0000000169532
3  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000123005
4  ACC0000000000004  ACC0000000000004
5  ACC0000000000005  ACC0000000000005
6  ACC0000000123005  ACC0000000000040
```