# Replace values of duplicated rows with first record in pandas?

Tags: pandas

**Input**

```
 df

id   label
a      1
b      2
a      3
a      4
b      2
b      3
c      1
c      2
d      2
d      3
```

**Expected**

```
  df

id   label
a      1
b      2
a      1
a      1
b      2
b      2
c      1
c      1
d      2
d      2
```

For `id` a, the `label` value is 1 and `id` b is 2 because 1 and 2 is the first record for a and b.

**Try**

I refer this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48781372/replace-other-columns-of-duplicate-rows-with-first-unique-value-and-create-looku), but still not solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update with `transform` `first`

```
df['lb2']=df.groupby('id').label.transform('first')
df
Out[87]: 
  id  label  lb2
0  a      1    1
1  b      2    2
2  a      3    1
3  a      4    1
4  b      2    2
5  b      3    2
6  c      1    1
7  c      2    1
8  d      2    2
9  d      3    2
```

Comment: @Jack ....did you try your sample data with my function ?

Comment: @Jack and please use this `df=pd.DataFrame({'id': {0: 'a', 1: 'b', 2: 'a', 3: 'a', 4: 'b', 5: 'b'},
 'label': {0: 1, 1: 2, 2: 3, 3: 4, 4: 2, 5: 3}})` and try my code

Comment: I updates my example, your function could not solve.

Comment: @Jack why C become 1 ?

Comment: @Jack check the update , please adding more explanation next time :-)

Comment: sorry, I should give more detail.

Comment: @Jack no worry happy coding